# Palavra em português europeu para o inglês "redeem"

Tags: tradução, português-europeu

Contextos:

a. Um cartão presente com um código.

b. Um cartão de débito-presente VISA ou MASTERCARD com 100 euros de saldo. Depois de gastar o dinheiro, o cartão pode ser recarregado com mas dinheiro.

Nestes contextos pode ser usada a palavra "resgatar" (redeem) em Portugal?

Comment: Portanto, o "gift card" é enviado pelo banco, certo? E o *redeem* neste contexto significa que já tens o €100 para gastar e depois o cartão acaba? Ou continua como  cartão de crédito normal?

Comment: Outra coisa, tens parte da pergunta em português, outra parte em inglês. Devia estar tudo na mesma língua.

Comment: Podes carregar dinheiro depois gastar os €100. Eu estou procurando por este contexto e o contexto em que você tem um código.

Comment: Eu utilizaria "Resgatar". Pode também colocar toda a sentança em inglês?

Comment: @Peixoto Tenho "Redeem a card" e "Redeem a coupon". No primeiro caso, se usa o dinheiro do cartão. No segundo caso, se usa um código. O cartão pode ser carregado com mais dinheiro, o código é usado apenas uma vez.

Comment: @RobertodeNobrega o que quer dizer com "Este cartão é resgatável?" Este cartão pode ser usadol?!

Comment: @JorgeB. Já mudei a maneira como fiz minha pergunta. Desculpa, eu ainda estou aprendendo português

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se for para ser em português europeu eu **não** aconselharia a utilizar a palavra *resgatar*, não é muito comum aqui. Só no caso de ser para *resgatar* pessoas de acidentes.

Mesmo assim acho que precisaria mais de contexto. Eu tenho pesquisado e *redeem* é usado com vários significados, mas poderia ser assim:

a) Descontar um cartão presente

Neste caso o *descontar* surge como **utilizar** o cartão numa compra, exemplo:

> Pode *descontar* o cartão presente em qualquer parte do mundo.

b) Reutilizar um cartão

Neste caso o *reutilizar* surge como usar uma segunda vez, recarregando-o, exemplo:

> Pode *reutilizar* o seu cartão VISA recarregando-o no nosso balcão.

Acho que **usar** ou **utilizar** também são boas alternativas, mas depende sempre do contexto. Uma frase onde se encaixe o que pretende era mais simples de explicar.

Pode ver o exemplo do NetFlix em [Português](https://help.netflix.com/pt-pt/node/32950):

[image]

E em [Inglês](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/32950):

[image]